# Filter cards based on two variables with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have multiple cards populated from MySQL database. I want to allow realtime search to filter cards based on Account number and Username. I tried the following code but it didn't work. Please advise. The JS code used is the typical one from W3 tutorial and tailored to fit my code.

```js
function Function() {
    // Declare variables
    var input, filter, div, carddiv, acc, name, i;
    input = document.getElementById("BankSearch");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    div = document.getElementById("Bank-Approval");
 carddiv = div.children();
 
    // Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query
    for (i = 0; i < carddiv.length; i++) {
        acc = carddiv[i].getElementsByTagName("div")[0].getElementsByTagName("div")[0].getElementsByTagName("h1")[0];
  name = carddiv[i].getElementsByTagName("div")[1].getElementsByTagName("div")[0].getElementsByTagName("h1")[0];
        if (acc.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            carddiv[i].show();
        } else {
    if (name.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            carddiv[i].show();
        } else {
   carddiv[i].hide();
        }
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="tab-content tab-space">
 <div id="Bank-Approval" class="collapse show" data-parent="#accordion" >
<!--Search CODE -->
  <span class="bmd-form-group">
   <div class="input-group">
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Search" maxlength="100" id="BankSearch" onkeyup="Function()" type="text">  
     <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <span class="input-group-text">       
       <i class="material-icons">search</i>
      </span>
     </div>
   </div>
  </span>
<!--Search CODE -->
<!--1st Card CODE -->
  <div class="card">
   <div class="card-header">
    <div id="Account Number">
     <h1>44444444444</h1>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="card-body">
    <div id="Name">
     <h1>XXXXXXX</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="Bank">
     <i src="banklogo/XXX.png"  width="80%" height="80%"></i>
    </div>
    <form >
     <input name="bank" value="XXX" type="hidden">
    </form>
    <button>Add</button>
    <button>Hide</button>
    <div id="Since">
     <h1>2 days ago</h1>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
<!--1st Card CODE -->
<!--2nd Card CODE -->
  <div class="card">
   <div class="card-header">
    <div id="Account Number">
     <h1>2222222222</h1>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="card-body">
    <div id="Name">
     <h1>YYYYYYY</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="Bank">
     <i src="banklogo/XXX.png"  width="80%" height="80%"></i>
    </div>
    <form >
     <input name="bank" value="XXX" type="hidden">
    </form>
    <button>Add</button>
    <button>Hide</button>
    <div id="Since">
     <h1>4 days ago</h1>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
<!--2nd Card CODE -->
 </div>
</div>
```

Two cards only displayed for example, it would be much more.

Comment: what didn't work? can you provide errors or behavior?

Comment: The error message given by the snippet says "`div.children is not a function`"; maybe related to `carddiv = div.children();`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you may be mixing jQuery syntax without referencing it. There are different ways to handle this, but a better option may be to select the cards by class name (see additional comments marked /**)

```
function Function() {
  // Declare variables
  var input, filter, div, carddiv, acc, name, i;
  input = document.getElementById("BankSearch");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();

  div = document.getElementById("Bank-Approval");
  carddiv = div.getElementsByClassName("card"); //** Select by class

  // Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < carddiv.length; i++) {
    //** Select specific parent element. innerText will return text in child h1.
    acc = carddiv[i].querySelector("[id='Account Number']").innerText;
    name = carddiv[i].querySelector("[id='Name']").innerText;

    if (acc.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      carddiv[i].style.display = "block"; //** .hide()/.show() is not supported
    } else {
      if (name.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        carddiv[i].style.display = "block";
      } else {
        carddiv[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
};
```